# Auto updating data coping Excel-VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I have an `Excel` file, having a sheet(`SheetA`) which is linked with a software to imports live market data, so it auto updates(every second) according to the  software it is linked to. I am taking some data from specific cells(which are not fixed and very large in number... other i could have just linked them) of `SheetA` to another sheet(`SheetB`) using `VBA` script to do some calculations, I want to know a way to keep my `SheetB` calculations automatically synchronized as `SheetA` updates its cell values. 
TIA

Comment: Put VBA script in `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` for sheet(`sheetA`)

Comment: Not an good idea. Update can make multiple changes in a worksheet... 
@AbhinavRawat What code do you use to update `Sheet A`?

Comment: @MichałTurczyn `SheetA` is linked with one of the trading software(New TT), which updates the sheet with live Market data automatically. for the code I mean they are just worksheet functions of NEW TT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since updating can raise multiple `Worksheet_Change` events, it's not practical to write copying routine in that method. More practical would be on workbook opening:
`Private Sub Workbook_Open()` method is responsible for this event. So, now data in `Sheet B` will be updated, when workbook will be opened (so before any work). Even if updating code is opening workbook, then event is raised only once, therefore, the code will execute only once.